# Page not found (404) error happens

Tags: python, html, django

I got an error,Page not found (404)  when I put logout button in detail.html.
I wrote in header.html

```
<header class="clearfix">
      <h1 class="title">WEB SITE</h1>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse head_content" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav top-menu">
          <li class="nav-item top-menu-item"><i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true">
            <a class="nav-link icon_head" href="/accounts/see">SEE</a></i>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown top-menu-item"><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle icon_head" href="" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              KNOW
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="/accounts/nowknow">KNOW1</a>
              </div>
              <div class="dropdown-content">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="/accounts/pastknow">KNOW2</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            </i>
          </li>  
        </ul>
      </div>
      <a class="logout_button" href="/accounts/logout_view">LOGOUT</a>
</header>
```

I wrote in views.py

```
    @login_required
    def logout_view(request):
        logout(request)
        return redirect('regist')

    @login_required
    def regist(request):
        return render(request, 'registration/regist.html')

    @login_required
    def see(request):
        return render(request, 'registration/see.html')

    @login_required
    def nowknow(request):
        return render(request, 'registration/nowknow.html')

    @login_required
    def pastknow(request):
        return render(request, 'registration/pastknow.html')

   @login_required
    def detail(request):
        return render(request, 'registration/detail.html')
```

in urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^product$', views.logout_view,name='logout_view'),
    url(r'^past_result$', views.see,name='see'),
    url(r'^privacy_policy$', views.nowknow,name='nowknow'),
    url(r'^privacy_policy$', views.pastknow,name='pastknow'),
    url(r'^detail$', views.detail,name='detail'),
]
```

I wrote in index.html

```
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    <title>WEB SITE</title>
</head>

<body class="relative">
{% include '../header.html' %}

    <main>
    <p>HELLO WORLD</p>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

When I acsess index.html and put LOGOUT link,logout is done accurately.But I wrote in detail.html

```
<html lang="ja">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

    <title>DETAIL</title>
</head>

<body class="relative">
{% include '../header.html' %}

    <main>
    <p>HOGE</p>
    </main>
</body>
</html>
```

and put LOGOUT link,the error happens.In this time,Request URL is http://localhost:8000/accounts/detail/logout_view.I really cannot understand why this error happens.I wrote 2 html same way,so I cannot know why one of html is ok but another causes the error.How should I fix this?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `@login_required` decorator from `logout_view()`?

Comment: It looks like your first template has `"/accounts/logout_view"` as the logout URL, but in the urls file you have `url(r'^product$', views.logout_view,...`

Answer (score 3):

For some reason you have defined your URL for the logout_view view as "product", so that's the URL you need to use.

To avoid this sort of problem, you should always use the `{% url %}` tag to generate the URL, rather than hard-coding it in the template:

```
<a class="logout_button" href="{% url 'logout_view' %}">LOGOUT</a>
```

Comment: thx ur answer.I wrote ur code,but same error happens and url link sends to http://localhost:8000/accounts/detail/logout_view.How should I do to fix this?

Comment: Good luck Daniel ;-)